# Floyd's Triangle right pattern

Tags: c

I have to creat a program thats that asks from the user to enter a number of rows and then creats a floyd's triangle. The problem is i don't seem to manage to make this particular pattern:

```
      1
    2 3
  4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

I have only managed to creat the basic program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rows, r, c, a;
int number=1;

int main()
{

    printf("Floyd Triangle\n");
    printf("--------------");
    printf("\nPlease enter an integer number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    while(rows<=0)
    {
      printf("\nYou must enter an integer value: ");
      scanf("%d",&rows);
    }

    for(r=1;r<=rows;r++)
    {
      for(c=1;c<=r;+c++)
      {
       printf("%d ", number++);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
```

there are no erros in my code so far

Comment: There is at least the error of a missing brace in your _code so far_.

Comment: @pmg did you click on the link? it wouldnt let me put a picture so i found a pettern on google. what i want is the numbers to be aligned to the right

Comment: @Armali missing brace? sorry its my first month at the university so im really an amateur

Comment: You can edit the question by adding a line `~~~` and an example of the desired output. It is still unclear whether you want only the numbers in each column aligned to the right of each other, or all rows right-justified, or a combination of both.

Comment: @Armali ok i just edited the question and managed to put a picture

Comment: @pmg - You changed the output pattern given by the querist to one which matches your answer. Do you think that's okay?

Comment: @Armali: my bad, I've now removed the introduced beautification

Comment: @pmg - No offense, I'm not even sure that JohnEm doesn't like your beautification. :-) JohnEm - You should make clear whether you care if the output looks exactly as in your picture.

Comment: @pmg i haven't learnt how to make my own functions yet. isnt there a way to accomplish this only by using loops?

Comment: @Armali the photo was a screenshot from the excersise so this is the wanted output. it should look like this no matter how many rows the user enters. By the way im sorry if im making this hard for you, its my first time using this forum and also im not really experienced with C yet

Answer (score 0):

Just print some spaces before the first number in each row

```
    // ...
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        printsomespaces(r, rows); // prints some spaces depending on current row and total rows
        for (c = 0; c < r; +c++) {
            printf("%d ", number++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    // ...
```

If you can't write your own function (no `printsomespaces`) use a loop instead:

```
        //...
        //printsomespaces(r, rows);
        for (int space = 0; space < XXXXXXXX; space++) putchar(' ');
        //...
```

where `XXXXXXXX` is some calculation using `r` and `rows`.
Try (untested) `2 * (rows - r)` (2 is the width of each number: 1 for the number + 1 for the space).

Comment: No, you have to write the function yourself, maybe give it a name you like better!

Comment: funny thing is there's a second question to that problem that asks me to make the numbers appear in a 'isosceles triangle' pattern and by doing what u said that is the output i get. so u still helped me finish part of the exercise. ill try to use this to make the other pattern too. thanks

Comment: So you just need more spaces for the first question :)

Answer (score 0):

> i haven't learnt how to make my own functions yet. isnt there a way to accomplish this only by using loops?

There is. A main problem of this exercise is to compute the needed width of each column, which of course depends on the number in the bottom row. The count of digits of a number can be determined in various ways; perhaps the easiest is via the `snprintf(char *s, size_t n, const char *format, ...)` function, which

> … returns the number of characters that would have been written
>   had `n` been sufficiently large…
>
> If `n` is zero, nothing is written,
>   and `s` may be a null pointer.

```
    // we need to compute the width the of widest number of each column
    int width[rows];
    const int max = rows*(rows+1)/2;    // the greatest number
    for (c=1; c<=rows; ++c) // see how many characters will be written
        width[c-1] = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d ", max-rows+c);
    for (r=1; r<=rows; ++r, puts(""))
        for (c=1; c<=rows; ++c)
            if (c <= rows-r)    // here comes an empty cell in this row
                printf("%-*c", width[c-1], ' ');
            else
                printf("%-*d", width[c-1], number++);
```